# Java Multi-Catch/Rethrow

Tags: java, exception

If I do the following using a multi-catch in Java 1.7:

```
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException ex) {
    logger.error("Array out of bounds exception in BatchTableRow constructor: data was: table = " +
            schema.toString() + ", data: " + sourceRow.toString(), ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Will the re-thrown exception maintain the exception type that originally entered the catch clause?  What if I catch 3 kinds of exceptions including the base "Exception" class - will it always remain the most specific one available in the list?

Comment: It just rethrows the caught `ex` object - no changes are made. Be wary of the "catch, log and rethrow" pattern - it often leads to double-logging and obtuse exception handling.

Comment: If you have Exception as one of the types, you do not need the others.

Comment: It's recommended use particular exception instate on global. Still if you want to do same the answer is yes, you re-thrown and it re-thrown the  specific one available in the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will the re-thrown exception maintain the exception type that originally entered the catch clause?

Yes - it will rethrow the exact same exception object. You need to differentiate between the *compile-time* type of `ex` (which is effectively the upper bound of the declared types) and the *execution-time* type of the value of `ex`, which is a reference to a specific object. The object's type won't change just because you've caught the exception.

Answer (score 5):

> Will the re-thrown exception maintain the exception type that originally entered the catch clause?

The re-thrown exception will maintain its **own** exception type immaterial of which exception type was specified that made it enter the `catch` clause.

Say, you've caught an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception with your `catch` block specified with `Throwable`. Now, even though you re-throw this exception through a `Throwable` *reference*, you can again `catch` it (higher up the stack) with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (or any of its *superclass* types)  since the exception object itself never lost its *type*.

It's just that you're using exception *references* of **different** types (depending on how you defined your `catch` block) to point to the **same** exception object.

Comment: this is not clear; even if the runtime type of the exception is the same, when you rethrow it as a Throwable,you can't catch it up the call stack as a more specific type,since you're forced to handle the exception that is thrown as the type declared by the method (unless you cast it explicitly)

Comment: @Luca I just took *Throwable* as an example; OP was actually throwing *unchecked* exceptions so he could catch them up the call stack directly. Yes, with *Throwable*, you'll need a *catch(Throwable e)* but there's no need for a cast as you'll have the *catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)* above it.